# Show/Hide panel not working in usercontrol

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hide, panel

i am trying to show/hide panel when user clicks the button. Everything is working fine when i paste this code in .aspx page, but if this code is in usercontrol, it is not working. Any suggestions?
Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideOne() {
        if (document.getElementById('<%=CommentPanel.ClientID %>').style.display == "none") {
            document.getElementById('<%=CommentPanel.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('<%=CommentPanel.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
        }
        return false;
    } </script>
    <asp:Button ID="btnShowComments" runat="server" Text="Comments" OnClientClick="javascript:return ShowHideOne();"/>      
    <asp:Panel ID="CommentPanel" runat="server">
        ToDo: COMMENTS!
    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Are you placing the code in usercontrol (i.e. using script tag too)?

Comment: this is the only code that i pasted in usercontrol

Answer (score 0):

Your code is still working normally in usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnShowComments" runat="server" Text="Comments" OnClientClick="ShowHideOne();"/>
```